# Align a programmatically created UIView's center with an auto-layout view's center

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard

I created an `UIView` in Storyboard that is to be centered exactly in the center of the View Controller with auto layout, and is working fine across different device sizes. I call this `largerView`.

However, I would like to programmatically create a smaller `UIView` called `smallerView` and **center** the this view so that `smallerView.center = largerView.center`.

I am running into an issue where given that **auto layout** is used on `largerView`, whenever I use the method above, my `smallerView` never actually centers with `largerView.center`. I noticed that it will take the center coordinates of `largerView` as they appear in Storyboard, based on the specific layout of the device I am using (in this case, the previous iPhone 5's dimensions), but not the updated center as affected by auto layout.

A similar issue may be [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851112/centering-modal-view-with-autolayout) here, except it is based on Swift. I know how constraints are created programmatically, but am unsure how to get the "refreshed" coordinates of a view after auto layout is applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override the following method in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.smallView.frame.center = self.largeView.frame.center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If your smallerView is subview of largerView:

```
self.smallerView.center = CGPointMake(self.largerView.frame.size.width / 2, self.largerView.frame.size.height / 2);
```

If your smallerView have same superview as largerView:

```
self.smallerView.center = self.largerView.center;
```